# Weird behavior of ggplot2::geom_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want ggplot() to label observations with residuals higher than 1.5 times the standard error of the regression. The data are these (from [Frank 1984](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1805123)):

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(43,32,32,30,26,25,23,22,22,21,20,20,19,19,19,18,18,17,17,16,16,16,15,13,12,12,10,10,9,7,6,3), y=c(63.0,54.3,51.0,39.0,52.0,55.0,41.2,47.7,44.5,43.0,46.8,42.4,56.5,55.0,53.0,55.0,45.0,50.7,37.5,61.0,48.1,30.0,51.5,40.6,51.3,50.3,62.4,39.3,43.2,40.4,37.7,27.7))
```

The model is simple:

```
m <- lm(y~x,data=d)
```

Then the ggplot() is:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_text(label=ifelse(abs(resid(m))>(1.5*sigma(m)),rownames(d),""), 
        nudge_x = 1, nudge_y = 0, check_overlap = T, color="blue")
```

giving this plot

[image]

which is missing a label for the observation in the top left corner (obs #27). Compare:

```
abs(resid(m))>(1.5*sigma(m))
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30    31    32 
FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

which indicates correctly that 27 satisfies the condition. Why is it not labelled?

Comment: Testing your code suggests it has something to do with `check_overlap = TRUE`, but I can't figure out why that is interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your labels in `geom_text` aren't inside an `aes` like they should be, although I'm unsure why you still got partially working labels without it.

I'm including some intermediate steps to work through this more slowly; for me, that helps with debugging and investigating how things work. Feel free to condense.

Assigning `d` and `m` are identical to the OP. With the extra steps:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d2 <- d %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(abs_resid = abs(resid(m)), sig = sigma(m)) %>%
  mutate(is_outlier = abs_resid > 1.5 * sig) %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(is_outlier, row, ""))

head(d2)
#>    x    y row  abs_resid      sig is_outlier label
#> 1 43 63.0   1  4.8398378 7.934235      FALSE      
#> 2 32 54.3   2  0.9561793 7.934235      FALSE      
#> 3 32 51.0   3  2.3438207 7.934235      FALSE      
#> 4 30 39.0   4 13.4681223 7.934235       TRUE     4
#> 5 26 52.0   5  1.2832746 7.934235      FALSE      
#> 6 25 55.0   6  4.7211239 7.934235      FALSE

ggplot(d2, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), nudge_x = 1, color = "blue")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-31 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks camille! The missing `aes` was indeed the problem. Weird that ggplot() spit out some values rather than stopping with an error message.